# Drawbacks of explicitly implementing not used interface

Tags: java, oop

I came up with this question writing specific code, but I'll try to keep the question as generic as possible.

Other similar question refer to C# which seems to have some language specific handling for this and below code is Java, but again let's try to keep it generic.

Let's say I have class A which implements interface I.

This is useful to me cause I can implement methods that use A only as a I type and abstract the implementation.

<strike>Let's now say, I have class B which implements all methods in interface I, but it's never referred to as only I.</strike>
Let's now say, I have class B which implements methods that have the same name/signature as the ones in interface I, but it doesn't implements the interface.

Should I always explicitly implement I?
Even if I don't use it (though I might in the future) for type abstraction?

A more meaningful, even if probably not realistic, example would be:

```
interface Printable {
   String print()

class A implements Printable {
   //code...
   String print(){return "A";}
   //code...
}

class B {
   //code...
   String print(){return "B";}
   void otherMethod(){/*code*/}
   //code...
}

class Test {
   Printable a = new A();
   System.out.println(a.print());
   B b = new B();
   b.otherMethod();
   System.out.println(b.print());
}
```

Are there any drawbacks on explicitly implementing, or not, the interface Printable?

The only one I can think of is scalability for the second case.
In the sense that if one day I'll want to explicitly use it as Printable, I'll be able to do so without any more effort.

But is there anything else (patterns, optimization, good programming, style, ..) I should take into consideration?

Comment: If you have an interface that is built exactly to provide the methods that you need in your class then it would probably be a good idea to implement that interface. A potential drawback is implementing an external interface "just because it has fitting methods", having that external interface change and then you are left with methods to implement you neither needed nor wanted. I would say it's a matter of a use-case. In your simple example I would surely implement the interface, there is no harm in doing so. But I don't think there is a general answer for this.

Comment: "Let's now say, I have class B which implements all methods in interface I, but it's never referred to as only I." this statement is wrong. Your class B implements methods which have the same name/signature as the ones in your interface, but it doesn't implement the methods of the interface.

Comment: In Java: If you don't have any reference to an other class, the compiler see the method as a member of the current class.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the type hierarchy will affect the method call cost due to not playing well with JIT method inlining. An example of that can be found in [Guava ImmutableList (and others) offer awful performance in some cases due to size-optmized specializations #1268](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1268) bug:

> Many of the guava Immutable collections have a cute trick where they have specializations for zero (EmptyImmutableList) and one (SingletonImmutableList) element collections. These specializations take the form of subclasses of ImmutableList, to go along with the "Regular" implementation and a few other specializations like ReverseImmutable, SubList, etc.
>
> Unfortunately, the result is that when these subclasses mix at some call site, the call is megamorphic, and performance is awful compared to classes without these specializations (worse by a factor of 20 or more).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple correct answer for this question.

However, if you do not implement the method, you should do this:

```
public void unusedBlahMethod() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("operation blah not supported");
}
```

The advantages of omitting the unused method are:

1. You save yourself time and money (at least in the short term).
2. Since you don't need the method, it might not be clear to you how best to implement it anyway.

The disadvantages of omitting the method are:

1. If you need the method in the future, it will take longer to add it as you may have to refamiliarize yourself with the code, check-out, re-test, etc.
2. Throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` may cause bugs in the future (though good test coverage should prevent that).

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing disposable code, you don't need to write interfaces, but one day you might notice, that you should've taken your time and write an interface.

The main advantage and purpose of interfaces is the flexibility of using different implementations. I can put something, that offers the same functionality inside a method, I can create a fake of it for test purposes and I can create a decorator that behaves like the original object, but can log the stuff.

Example:

```
public interface A {
    void someMethod();
}

public class AImplementation {
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class ADecorator {
    private final A a;

    public ADecorator(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Before method call");
        a.someMethod();
        System.out.println("After method call");
    }
}
```

Nice side effect: ADecorator works with every implementation of A. 
The cost for this flexibility isn't that high and if your code will live a little bit longer, you should take it.